# Grabbing rows with PDO

Tags: php, web, count, pdo, rows

I'm attempting at seeing if there is already a row in a table in my database. If there is a row then the php will redirect to a different page. If there isn't a row, it will stay there. Here is the code that I have:

```
$sched_ex = $db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(1) FROM sched WHERE uid = '$uid'");
$sched_ex->execute();

if($sched_ex == 0) { ... } else { redirect }
```

I'm new to PDO, not sure what I need to do for it to work properly.

Edit:

```
$sched_ex = $db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(1) FROM sched WHERE uid = :uid");
$sched_ex->execute(array(':uid' => $uid));

if($sched_ex->fetchColumn() == 0) { a lot of html }
else {
?>
<script langauge="javascript">
    window.location="../"
</script>
<?php
}
```

Header wasn't working, so I used JavaScript. I doubt that's the issue, though.

Comment: in php you can redirect with: ```header("location: <url>");```

Comment: One has to call `exit` after calling `header` for it to work properly. Have you tried to view source and see if it goes through one branch or the other? Are you sure `$uid` is set? Are you sure the data in the database has the number of records you assume?

Comment: I fixed the header problem. I always forget that exits have to be called post. $uid is set from the users session.

There is currently only one row in the table. What I'm trying to get this code to do is recognize that there is that row there, because if it is then they cannot be on that page and when attempting to go there get redirected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, use bound parameters to protect your self against injection attacks:

```
$sched_ex = $db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(1) FROM sched WHERE uid = :uid");
$sched_ex->execute(array(':uid' => $uid));
```

Secondly, as for your question:

```
if($sched_ex->fetchColumn() == 0) { ... } else { redirect }
```

(See: http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php)

Comment: It's not working for me. Can you think of anything I may be doing wrong?

Comment: Possibly the way you redirect. Can you show the full code for the if-block.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [rowcount](http://au.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php) function to find out how many rows there are (if the query returned anything), then you will need to actually fetch he data.

But on that note, from the docs:

*For most databases, PDOStatement::rowCount() does not return the number of rows affected by a SELECT statement. Instead, use PDO::query() to issue a `SELECT COUNT(*)` statement with the same predicates as your intended SELECT statement, then use PDOStatement::fetchColumn() to retrieve the number of rows that will be returned. Your application can then perform the correct action.*

You need to [fetch](http://au.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php) the rows after the execute:

```
$dbh = new PDO($this->mySQLAccessData->hostname, $this->mySQLAccessData->username, $this->mySQLAccessData->password);
$stmt = $dbh->query($sql);
$stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_INTO, new kpiData);
$dataCount=0;
foreach($stmt as $kpiData)
{
    $arrKPIData[$dataCount]['year']=$kpiData->year;
    $arrKPIData[$dataCount]['month']=$kpiData->month;
    $dataCount++;
    unset($stmt);
}
```